# Как пропарсить страницу с помощью request python?

Tags: python, requests

Есть сайт https://zdravcity.ru/information/
При просмотре когда сайта в браузере я нахожу ссылки, которые мне нужны
[image: При просмотре когда сайта в браузере я нахожу ссылки, которые мне нужны]

Если же делаю get запрос, то ничего подобного в коде не нахожу, а это то, что мне нужно. Как правильно составить запрос, чтобы эти ссылки находились?

```
requests.get("https://zdravcity.ru/information/", headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.39'}
```

Comment: нужно просто запрашивать правильную страницу. Дефолтная страница не знает откуда Вы и дает Вам левый адрес. Запрашивайте правильную страницу.

Comment: используйте селениум.

Comment: Селениум не годится, нужен реквест. Так а какая страница правильная?

Comment: Когда первый раз заходите на страницу, оно спрашивает, где живете. Запоминает. а потом уже не спрашивает. Так что либо подсовывайте куки, либо просто дайте правильную ссылку. Она у Вас прям на скриншоте подчеркнута. Хотя зачем...

Comment: вопрос как раз в том, как выцепить эту ссылку? при реквесте её нет. А при просмотре когда страницы она есть. Видимо, там что-то динамически подгружается. Я и не знаю, как это подгрузить. А этом вопрос состоит.